# kivy filechooserlistview not filling up screen

Tags: python, kivy

Im making a simple app in Kivy that needs to use the FileChooserListView widget. For some reason whenever I try using the widget, it only covers the lower left hand side of the app. I can't get it to fill the entire screen like its supposed to.
Here is what happens to my app:

[image: kivy app result]

main.py:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class AppRoot(BoxLayout):
    img_picker = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.img_picker = ImagePicker()

    def change_to_img_picker(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(self.img_picker)

    def change_to_about_us(self):
        print "change_to_about_us"

class ImagePicker(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def open(self, path, selection):
        print "OPEN"

    def selected(self, selection):
        print "SELECTION"

class ImageApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AppRoot()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ImageApp().run()
```

image.kv:

```
AppRoot:

<AppRoot>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: root.width * .02, root.height * .02
    spacing: 10
    Label:
        text: "Some text should go here"
    Button:
        text: "Select Image"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: root.height * .1
        on_release: root.change_to_img_picker()
    Button:
        text: "About the App"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: root.height * .1
        on_release: root.change_to_about_us()

<ImagePicker>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    id: img_picker
    Button:
        text: "open"
        on_release: root.open(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
        size_hint: 1, .2
    FileChooserListView:
        id: filechooser
        on_selection: root.selected(filechooser.selection)
        size_hint: 1, .8
```

The change_to_img_picker() function should replace the current widgets with the FileChooserListView and take up all the space. I'm not sure why it's not working. I would appreciate it if anyone would enlighten me as to why this is happening. Thank You in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The problem is that you call super on BoxLayout, not for your ImagePicker class (the first argument should be the *current* class, not the parent). This messes up the binding that is normally created in the BoxLayout's `__init__` (probably this is simply not called any more, you get the BoxLayout parent's `__init__` instead), so the normal layout triggers are absent and the change of size etc do not affect the children.

I'm not completely sure of some of the details (in particular, I'm surprised that the layout for your root widget seems to work fine), but this seems to be the core of the problem.